# Trying to remember name of a SciFi movie where an astronaut on the moon uses a rat to find his ship

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I can remember is the end and a lost astronaut on the moon uses a rat on a key ring to decide which way to go to find his ship.

Comment: Do you remember how he uses it? Does it talk to him, or does he flip it like a coin?

Comment: Roughly when did you see it? Did you see it in a theater, on tv, or disc/download/streaming? Was it in color? Was it in English? Was the astronaut a male? Even small details could help narrow this down.

Comment: He just holds it up and lets its nose point in the direction

Answer (score 9):

The movie is [Countdown](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062827/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_95) (1968) starring James Cann and Robert Duval.

From a book called '[The Pilgrim Project](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2541834.The_Pilgrim_Project)' by Hank Searls. I read the book as a kid before the movie came out.

Comment: If someone wants to copy a summary from Wikipedia to an answer perhaps they could answer the question themselves, noting this answer isn't accepted. It seems a bit outre to add a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(1968_film)) plot summary of 457 words directly copied to my short answer for such a short question. Now if someone had only made a move from "Autopsy  for A Cosmonaut" by Jacob Hay as well.